# Wrap JWS in another JWS

Tags: jwt

I have a JWT which is created by a source server. Before the JWT goes to the destination server it passes through another intermediate service which verifies, adds some extra data and signs. I need the destination to verify it came from both services and obtain the `extra_data`

I was thinking the final JWT will look like the following

```
const token = JWT({
sub: 'ey....,
extra_data: 123,
})
```

and the code I will use to verify and get data would look like:

```
const { sub, extra_data } = jwt.verify(token, publicKeyIntermediate);
const { data } = jwt.verify(sub, publicKeySource);

const finalPayload = {
extra_data,
...data,
}
```

Is this the correct way to deal with this situation?